# About the current of finite mass

Tags: complex-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In Demailly's e-book  *Complex analytic and differential geometry*, 
chap3-(1.14) Proposition is stated as follows:

Every positive current $T=i^{(n-p)^{2}} \sum T_{I, J} d z_{I} \wedge d \bar{z}_{J}$ in $\mathscr{D}_{p, p}^{\prime+}(X)$ is real and of order 0, i.e. its coefficients $T_{I . J}$ are complex measures and satisfy $\overline{T_{I . J}}=T_{J, I}$ for all multi-indices $|I|=|J|=n-p .$ Moreover $T_{I, I} \geqslant 0,$ and the absolute values $\left|T_{I, J}\right|$
of the measures $T_{I, J}$ satisfy the inequality
$$
\lambda_{I} \lambda_{J}\left|T_{I, J}\right| \leqslant 2^{p} \sum_{M} \lambda_{M}^{2} T_{M, M}, \quad I \cap J \subset M \subset I \cup J
$$
where $\lambda_{k} \geqslant 0$ are arbitrary coefficients and $\lambda_{I}=\prod_{k \in I} \lambda_{k}$

**My first question is** :what is the definition of the absolute value of distribution $T_{I,J}$. Distribution is a global quantity , what is its pointwise value.

**My 2-nd question is:** how can we view the  **mass measure** $\|T\|:=\sum\left|T_{I, J}\right|$ of a positive current  as? What confuses me is the same reason as the first question(Distribution is a global quantity , what is its pointwise value.)

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalVariation.html